# OAuth authentication in R with a temporary request token

Tags: r, oauth, etsy

I'm trying to access Etsy sales data through the Etsy developer API. This requires authentication , which is detailed [here](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth). I'm then trying to perform these authentication steps in R, using `httr`:

```
etsy_endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(request = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token",
                            authorize = NULL,
                            access = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/access_token")

etsy_app <- oauth_app("etsy",
                   key = api_key,
                   secret = shared_secret)



token <- oauth1.0_token(
  etsy_endpoint,
  etsy_app
)
```

But this doesn't seem to work as according to the Etsy documentation a temporary request token needs to be generated, to obtain the authorisation URL that is required? (this step in the documentation)

```
// instantiate the OAuth object
// OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY and OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET are constants holding your key and secret
// and are always used when instantiating the OAuth object 
$oauth = new OAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);

// make an API request for your temporary credentials
$req_token = $oauth->getRequestToken("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=email_r%20listings_r", 'oob', "GET");

print $req_token['login_url']."\n";
```

I've also tried a with the `ROAuth` package but have run into a similar issue.

For other websites there appears to be an authorisation URL that would be used as the reqest/access are in my example, but for Etsy this seems to be dynamically generated by a token request?

For reference, [this](https://github.com/sscheetz/etsy-python2/blob/d4055d76139ea4ca7d4580b37f755bc5a4f03467/etsy2/oauth.py#L24) source code in Python performs the authentication with Etsy, but I can't find any R functions to mirror some of the ones that are used, and don't have the OAuth knowledge to replicate them myself.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

The error received from the code above is as follows.

```
Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I assume this is because of the endpoint parameter `authorize = NULL`.

If I put, for example, `authorize = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth"`. Then a browser instance is opened and a generic file (125B) is downloaded, but nothing actually happens.

As another update, the original code is a reproducible example, but an Etsy developer account would need to be opened (for free) to get the relevant keys.

A developer account can be created [here](https://www.etsy.com/uk/join?from_page=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.etsy.com%2Fdevelopers%2Fregister), if anyone is able to try and replicate this issue

Edit2:

If anyone else is trying to register to get keys, the following steps worked for me on a fresh account:

I registered an Etsy account (with a new email), which then directs me to the "Create new app page".

Annoyingly, from here you have to confirm your email and enable two-factor authentication.

Then you can fill out the form, I used the following to just test it:

- Name: Test app.
- Description: "Testing Oauth authentication".
- Type: Seller tools.
- Users: Just myself.
- Commercial: No.
- Any of the following: Read sales data.

This process worked and then took me to the page with both security keys.

Comment: When you say, "This doesn't seem to work" what do you mean. Do you mean that you get an error? Do you mean you don't get the data you expected? Please be specific.

Comment: @AdamSampson thank you! Really appreciate the feedback, I've edited some more info into the post. The issue is that the R function expects a URL in the authorize parameter. As far as I can tell this is because the  `oauth1.0_token` function expects a very strict format, which Etsy's authentication process doesn't quite follow.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It might take a while for someone to come up with time to create an account to help you on this one. But it's good to know it's free to get a develp account.

Comment: @Aidan somehow I can't register

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk thanks for trying, that's really odd though! I'll try to setup a fresh account when I log on tomorrow and see if that's possible (not sure about the security concerns but definitely don't think handing out secret keys is a good idea...)

Comment: @Aidan it's definitely not a good idea.

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Hi, I've just had a chance to try out the process, and it seems to work for me? I register an Etsy account, which then directs me to the "Create new app page". Annoyingly, from here you have to confirm your email and enable two-factor authentication. Then you can fill out the form, I used the following to just test it:
Name: Test app. Description: "Testing Oauth authentication". Type: Seller tools. Users: Just myself. Commercial: No. Any of the following: Read sales data.

This process worked and then took me to the page with both security keys. Thanks again for the help!!